# Can you dynamically call an object from a DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Say I have a DLL right that  contains this:

```
//DLL 
 class foo { 
  static __declspec int Add(int a, int b)
  { 
  return a+b
  }
 }
```

How Do I call it call the GetProc Address? I.e:

```
HINSTANCE hFoo = LoadLibrary("Foo.dll");
int* proc = NULL;
proc = (int*) GetProcAddress(hFoo, ??????);
 //Main Exec linked to dll
```

***How in the world would you get the address of a class created in a dll using GetProcAddress?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`edtheprogrammerguy` is right.

Here is more informations on how to get class properly exposed:

You need to prefix with the attribute :

```
__declspec(dllexport)...
```

all the features you want to expose.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/a90k134d.aspx).

Example for a C function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Add(int a, int b)
{
  return (a + b);
}
```

This can be simplified using `MACROS`: everything is explained on this [helpful page](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/).

**For C++ classes, you only need to prefix each class (not every single method)**

I usually do it that way :

> Note : *The following also ensures portability...*

***Include File :***

```
// my_macros.h
//
// Stuffs required under Windoz to export classes properly
// from the shared library...
// USAGE :
//      - Add "-DBUILD_LIB" to the compiler options
//
#ifdef __WIN32__
#ifdef BUILD_LIB
#define LIB_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIB_CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define LIB_CLASS       // Linux & other Unices : leave it blank !
#endif
```

***Usage :***

```
#include "my_macros.h"

class LIB_CLASS MyClass {
}
```

Then, to **build**, simply :

- Pass the option `-DBUILD_LIB` to the usual compiler command line
- Pass the option `-shared` to the usual linker command line

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the address of a class from a .dll.  If you want to use a class instance from a .dll, use dllexport/dllimport, which lets you export the class and use it as if it were declared locally.

Reference from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to create an example of **Explicit Linking** Here is the example I finally came up with, I apologize for not specifically mentioning this earlier.

Here we go:

```
//DLL
#include "main.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class FOO{
static __declspec double ADD(double a, double b)
{
    return a+b;
}
}




   //EXEC
  #include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
typedef double (*MYPROC)(double, double);

int main()
{
    double d1 = 10;
    double d2 = 30;
    double retval;
    MYPROC  procx = NULL;
    DWORD err;
    HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary("DynamicLinkTester.dll");
    if(hDll != NULL)
    {
    cout << "Success";
    procx = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(hDll, "_ZN7MathDLL5MathX3ADDEdd");
    if(NULL != procx )
    {
        retval=  (procx)(d1, d2);
        cout << retval;
    }
    }


}
```

If anyone was wondering the same thing as me:

While you can't explicitly call a class/object from a dll you can call its method.

Comment: what is "_ZN7MathDLL5MathX3ADDEdd"?